# Where can I get the English Language Packs for Crysis?

Tags: pc, crysis

I got today my original copy from Crysis Maximum Edition. I got it via Amazon Germany. The thing is that this copy only contains German, Turkish and Russian languages but I don't know any of those languages.

So long story short!

Is it possible to get an English Language Pack for Crysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else seems to be in this position, judging from [this post](http://www.techsupportforum.com/gaming-forum/pc-gaming-support/234738-crysis-english-pak-files-needed.html) on the Tech Support Forum.

The answers from the site moderators indicate that you can't legally download these.

> If you do not have the English pak on the CD like Koala said we wont be able to help you as it will infringe on EA's copyright agreement.

and

> Yes, there are different DVD's of the game with different contents (language pack), each DVD has a license agreement. So If you have a DVD from Australia and send it to Turkey but the Australian version has no Turkish language pack you are unable to alter the game due to the license agreement as it will be altering the original copy which resides on the DVD.

Comment: It seems you are right ... I will have to get my hands on an English copy of the game ... or start studying German! Thanks!